# Input type data not working with transparent background on mobile

Tags: html, css, datepicker

```
<input style="background-color:transparent; color:red;" class="col-xs-6" type="date" name="date">
```

I have the next input, and I want to have the background transparent and text color white.. and on desktop looks good, the problem is on mobile...the input is transparent but the text ('dd/mm/yy') it's transparent too or I have no idea why..nothing appears and I can't select the input to pick a date. What can I do?

I want an input type date with transparent background and with format something like this: mm/dd/yy.

Comment: Does it work with `background-color:transparent` removed?

Comment: please add your complete code,please be care about inline style it will override the all styles in your style sheet

Comment: update your code in jsfiddle or codepen